# How can I add video on my home page?

Tags: magento2

**I want to add video in my home page.I am using my custom theme.Can i add video without any extension.**

Comment: You can use any videos format that can use in web in Magento 2. Just go  to Admin -> Content -> Pages, and on the homepage add your video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Admin Panel -> Content -> Pages. Select home page and in `content` tab click `Show/hide editor`. And in this place you can place `<iframe>` code (if you want to show for example YouTube video), or you can place

```
<video controls> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

to share video from your server or external url.
Admin Panel -> Content -> Pages -> homepage:
[image]

Store view:
[image]

Comment: Thank You  it works.

Comment: glad, i could help you! :)

Comment: i have one more question if i want to add my own video then how can i add ?

Comment: I think you can upload your video to pub/media folder, and then in <source src=""> define your path to this video.

Comment: Video is uploaded but only audio runs

Comment: weird, i tried: ```<video controls="controls" width="300" height="150"> 
  <source src="http://localhost/your_project/pub/media/video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>```, and it works.

Comment: okay let me check what i am missing.

Comment: do you get any error? in console. or in .log files?

Comment: No. it only play audio.

Comment: maybe type of the video does not match? I'm guessing...

Comment: let me know if you figure out what was wrong. I'm curious. 
Did you try to put video from external url? Like i showed in answer?

Comment: i checked the format is rigth. I am trying to figure it out what is the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325358/html-video-player-plays-sound-but-not-video   maybe this will help

Comment: okay i will try this.

Comment: Thanks it's work